# Overlaying text onto of htop output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, htop

How do you filter the output of a constantly updating `bash` command so that text is overlayed on top of the output?

I'm using `tmux` to show multiple `htop` processes across numerous servers. Unfortunately `tmux` doesn't make it easy to label each pane, so I want to overlay the name of the server somewhere in the output. I don't care if it obscures a small part of the output.

Answer (score 2):

you can run `top` in batch mode (see `man top`) and instead loop it with `watch`. So f.ex. :

```
watch "hostname; top -b -n 1"
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `watch -t` so that the header isn't shown.  Might make it easier on the eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "htop" in my post. Your solution comes close to working with htop to, by replacing the top command with `echo q | htop`. However, it looks like `watch` doesn't interpret color codes correctly, resulting in a lot of visible escape characters mangling the output.

Answer (score 0):

tmux from 2.3 allows you to set a title in each pane border. Enable it in your
`~/.tmux.conf` with:

```
set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #{pane_title}"
set -g pane-border-status bottom
```

Then before running your `htop` command in each pane add a printf command in that pane that will send the appropriate escape sequence to dynamically set the pane title:

```
printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'remotehost'
```